# Retrieve deleted files

Tags: 18.04

I have Dell laptop Vostro 15, 3000 series. With factory instaled Ubuntu 16.04. Have some documents on Descktop. Recently upgrade system with 18.04. Dont know how system crashed and can not boot. Dell ask me to recover my laptop wich is i think install guest season of 16.04. And I dont have any files on Desktop nor in Download folder. I try with testdisc software but, it looks like can not see my files.
Help, please!

Comment: The guest session won't see any files in your own Desktop/Download folders.  I'd suggest booting Ubuntu 'live' media (eg. install media & using the "Try Ubuntu" option) and then navigate to your hdd/ssd & explore what's actually there. You may not need to restore; they just weren't visible to a 'guest' login.

Comment: I try that, but dont know where to look up. Desktop and Download folder are empty.

Comment: When using a 'live' media; the ~/Documents & ~/Downloads will be of the 'live' session in memory (created on boot, and destroyed on reboot or shutdown). You'll need to navigate to your hdd/ssd & navigate to /*wherever.it.mounts*/home/*your.username*/Documents for example..

Comment: I do that. Boot up sistem with live usb, but when check home folder on my hdd, its empty.

Comment: I would be asking Dell, the recovery system would be their creation, and they'll know it, and it was on their request that it was done as I read your question.  If you wait here, other users on this forum may have more specific knowledge to Ubuntu on pre-installed dell hardware that I lack...

Comment: Ok! Thank you, very much, for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Are you saying that you booted into recovery mode, or you used a recovery partition or disc to restore the laptop to the factory default software load?

If the first, then you may need to mount the partition where your Documents and Desktop directories are. A live recovery mode session is probably all in RAM, so you need to mount the hard drive partitions to see the files.

If the second, you're probably not going to be able to recover those files, particularly if you've already tried testdisk without success. Reinstalling the operating system would likely overwrite much of the disc, and certainly would overwrite the old inode tables.

Comment: I think second thing is. Dell have some recovery system which put it back factory 16.04. I'm not sure. But when sistem is boot up, it is in guest season, and ask me that all changes will be deleted after restart. Have new empfy desktop folder. Basicaly it looks like a new system. But guestion is. Does it exist any software for deep searching deleted files? Any other then testdisc.

Comment: From the command line, issue command:  _mount_ and tell me what it says.